# How to ignore document.querySelectorAll(); case sensitive

Tags: javascript, html

I"m trying to extract all class names where the class names begin with "userName_XXX"

Currently I have a code that goes a bit like this.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div[class^=userName_]");
var classArr = Array.prototype.map.call(list, function(div) {
    return div.className;
});
```

Where the returned arr holds all user classes. My issue is that there are some cases where the classes do not follow the exact case.

So I'll come across a class like this "username_XXX" and it won't pick that up because its case sensitive. Can anyone help me out here or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Tried following this. Still now luck. 
http://jsperf.com/case-insensitive-queryselectorall/2

Comment: Why do you have classes with two different spellings?

Comment: @Seth Unfortunately this is what the previous developers decided to do while building the site =/

Comment: Why not `document.querySelectorAll('div[class^=userName_], div[class^=username_]')` ?

Comment: @Sergio tried that. For some reason no luck :S

Comment: If this were my problem I'd be looking for the quickest way to fix the broken pages rather than trying to embed a workaround for bad code.

Comment: @Pointy Unfortunate given the circumstances of my situation I am unable to do so :(

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711853/7250868

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var classes = [],
    els = document.querySelectorAll("div[class*=userName_], div[class*=username_]");
for(var i=0; i<els.length; ++i) {
    var match = els[i].className.match(/(?:^|\s)(userName_\S{3})(?:$|\s)/i);
    if(match) classes.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(classes);
```

```html
<div class="userName_123">Produces "userName_123"</div>
<div class="userName_1234">Produces nothing</div>
<div class="username_abc">Produces "username_abc"</div>
<div class="foo userName_abc bar">Produces "userName_abc"</div>
```

Comment: is a there way to not have the amount of numbers that comes after userName_ be set to 3? and have it dynamic?

Comment: Yes. What can "XXX" mean, exactly? You say it's a number? Then, should it match "username_abc"?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from here: [Ignoring case sensitiveness in querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399089/ignoring-case-sensitiveness-in-queryselectorall/38399344#38399344)

At least Chrome and Firefox support the case-insensitivity qualifier `i` in an selector (as defined in here: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#overview)

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="foo" i]');
console.log(divs.length);  // should be 3 :)
```

```html
<div class="foobar">foobar</div>
<div class="Foobar">Foobar</div>
<div class="fOobar">fOobar</div>
```