# Ignoring case sensitiveness in querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, selectors-api

I have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something2')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:alert('something3')">Click</a>
<a href="javascript:prompt('something4')">Click</a>
```

Now, using `console.log(document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='javascript:prompt('],a[href^='javascript:alert(']"));` would fetch all such elements as NodeList.

But, I have the HTML text given with different case of letters in `javascript`. That is, look at the following code:

```
<a href="javaSCRIPT:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="JaVaScRIPt:prompt('something2')">Click</a>
<a href="javaSCRIpt:alert('something3')">Click</a>
<a href="JAVAscrIPt:prompt('something4')">Click</a>
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150256/how-to-ignore-document-queryselectorall-case-sensitive), but using `*=` instead of `^=` doesn't help. I know `^=` equates to **'starts with'**, but what does `*=` mean?

How can I write a generic `querySelectorAll` for all such permutations of `javascript`?

Comment: `*=` means that it contains the text, for example in jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: The `querySelector*` methods respect/use the CSS selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At least Chrome and Firefox support the case-insensitivity qualifier `i` in an selector (as defined in here: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#overview)

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="foo" i]');
console.log(divs.length);  // should be 3 :)
```

```html
<div class="foobar">foobar</div>
<div class="Foobar">Foobar</div>
<div class="fOobar">fOobar</div>
```

Comment: This answer would make sense a few years from now, but not today, unless the asker intends to support only Chrome and Firefox for some reason (which, judging by [this follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697440/compatibility-of-document-queryselectorall-in-ie-edge-and-safari), doesn't seem to be the case - but then that doesn't explain why they accepted this answer).

Comment: @BoltClock I accepted it soon after testing in only Chrome, and came to know only after 15 days that it doesn't work in IE/Edge. Will make an edit in the answer now referring the answer in the follow-up question.

Comment: @BoltClock The case-insensitivity qualifier [is supported](https://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/attribute-case-sensitivity/) on Edge as of version 79 (2020-01) and Safari as of version 9 (2015-09). The answer you linked does not work on IE anyway, since IE does not support `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @zrhoffman: As foretold. (I didn't mention Safari because neither did Andreas, but fair.) Edge didn't even need to implement the feature on its own - it gained it by switching to Chromium. The feature never made it to EdgeHTML. As discussed in the linked question, `querySelectorAll()` is not the issue - it has been supported since IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:not` pseudoselector and target all anchors that **don't** have the word `http`. This way you collect only the JS links. There's some normal anchors in the Snippet mixed in and they've been filtered out.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var NodeList = document.querySelectorAll('a:not([href*="http"]');

console.log(NodeList);
```

```html
<a href="javaSCRIPT:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="http://example.com/">Click</a>
<a href="javaSCRIPT:alert('something1')">Click</a>
<a href="JaVaScRIPt:prompt('something2')">Click</a>

<a href="https://google.com">Click</a>
<a href="JAVAscrIPt:prompt('something4')">Click</a>
```

Comment: Wow. This work much better when I have to exclude all only-`javascript` iframes :) Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, sir. `:not` comes in handy, but that one from Andreas is definitely one to write down and remember.