# Compatibility of document.querySelectorAll in IE, Edge and Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari, microsoft-edge, selectors-api

Reference answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38399344/5132413

Please refer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399089/ignoring-case-sensitiveness-in-queryselectorall/) and the answer linked [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38399344/5132413) works only in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.

I did some research and found that it (case insensitivity flag) isn't compatible. I need an equivalent in IE, Edge and Safari.

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="foo" i]');
```

Comment: This is CSS4, you shouldn't use that right now because there is no much support.

Comment: I'm using it without issues but I don't now what the "i" is for: so try document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="foo"]');

Comment: That is the case insensitivity qualifier. Check [this's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399089/ignoring-case-sensitiveness-in-queryselectorall/) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38399344/5132413).

Comment: "I did some research and found that it isn't compatible." What did your research turn up that suggests this is an issue with querySelectorAll and not the case insensitivity flag?

Comment: @BoltClock I meant, the case insensitivity flag isn't compatible with IE and Edge, because of CSS4. That's why I have quoted one of my questions and the answer to it. Edited now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since css level 4 is still in drafts, case-sensitivity selector is not compatible with most browsers. You may use filter method like this:

```
var divs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div')).filter(function(el){
   return el.className.match(/^foo/i);
});
```

---

**Update**: Need to state that you can now use css4 selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="foo" i]');
```

See [this link](https://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/attribute-case-sensitivity/) for browser compatibility.